# Client zip multiple fetch

Tags: javascript, zip

I'm developing a small application that allows the user to select some documents on the frontend and when they click "Download" a zip is being generated with all their documents.

I'm using client-zip for that. It all works fine with 1 document (1 fetch), but there's one small issue, I can't figure out. How can I add dynamic fetches based on the number of elements in an array?

My code so far:

```
    const allDownloads = [];

    async function downloadTestZip() {
      const code = await fetch(allDownloads[0]);
      const blob = await downloadZip([code]).blob();
      const link = document.createElement('a');

      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = 'test.zip';
      link.click();
      link.remove();    
    }
```

The `allDownloads=[]` is filled when the user checks the checkmark next to the document. So there can be up to 200 different docs.

Comment: I know I should make it clearer in the quick start, but *don't forget to revoke the Blob URL* (i.e. your function should probably end with `URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an array of Promises, and then await them all :

```
const promises = allDownloads.map( url => fetch(url) ); // or simply .map(fetch), as a shorthand

const codes = await Promise.all(promises);

// now codes is an array of codes (strings, probably?)
```

Answer (score 1):

To improve latency, you can use an async iterator (client-zip is happy to take that instead of an array).

```js
async function *lazyFetch() {
  for (const url of allDownloads) yield await fetch(url)
}

const blob = await downloadZip(lazyFetch()).blob()
```

Functionally it does the same thing as the solution with `Promise.all` (and it's barely more code). However, client-zip will be able to start processing the data **as soon as the first fetch Response is ready** (instead of all 200 of them).

#### How does that help ?

Creating the ZIP file involves some computations and copying. So if you let client-zip start early, all that CPU-intensive stuff can happen while the browser is handling the HTTP request for the next file.
Browsers typically have a pool of HTTP clients and they won't start 200 requests concurrently.